# Length constraint not adhered to exactly with JPA annotation and PGSql Schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a database schema with a table called Vector, which has a column called Name. The Name column is defined as a varchar(255).

I have a hibernate model entity that is annotated with @Column with the length specified at 255.

Trying to persist the object with a CRUDRepository does not throw an exception regarding the length of the Name until the length is at 262, which seems very bizarre to me.

Thoughts? I expect that assigning a Name of length 256 to throw the exception.

Comment: Using @Size fixes some of the constraint issues, but not all.

Comment: Life is easier when you don't use mixed-case column-names, or those that are PostgreSQL reserved words (name, text, date etc). However, this shouldn't affect the number of characters it stores. Can you (1) post the table-definition and (2) SELECT a row with more than 255 chars and show everyone please?

Comment: Hibernate version? PostgreSQL version? Exact text content you're trying to persist?

Comment: @RichardHuxton, well using name is a lot more annoying pre-8.3 than after.  Post 8.3 it is safe enough but pre8.3 if you called your column something other than "name" and tried "select name from mytable" you'd get rather amusing results.